# How to watch Jenkins build server hardware tech specs?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to watch the hardware that is used in the Jenkins build server from the web control panel?

Answer (score 2):

With "watch the hardware" do you mean monitoring resources like CPU, memory, etc?

The "Monitoring" plugin works great for keeping an eye on the resource use of the Jenkins server - see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring.

You can see CPU load, memory usage, number of processes and other trends over time.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying question, I meant tech specs of the server.